# How would I extract a SQL count from the following schema?

Tags: sql, sum

Suppose I have a table MEETING as follows

```
M_DATE
M_RACE_NO
M_VENUE
M_ATHLETE
```

The primary key is date, race no, venue, athlete.  Each date/race no/venue can contain a number of possible athletes.  Suppose for particular athlete I wish to extract date, race no, venue as well as the total number of athletes competing in that particular date/race no/venue

e.g.  Suppose athlete Bolt competed in two events with total fields of 7 and 9 I would want something like the following

```
2011-10-03, 4, NY, 7
2010-24-02, 5, SY, 9
```

I know it would look something like

```
SELECT M_DATE, M_RACE_NO, M_VENUE, SUM(...) FROM MEETING WHERE M_ATHLETE='Bolt'
```

I'm not sure what goes after SUM

Comment: what RDBMS (Oracle / MySQL / ...)? does it support window functions - i.e. `count(...) over (...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your RDBMS supports this:

```
SELECT M_DATE, M_RACE_NO, M_VENUE,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY M_DATE, M_RACE_NO, M_VENUE)
FROM MEETING
WHERE M_ATHLETE='Bolt'
```

if not:

```
select m1.m_date, m1.m_race_no, m1.m_venue, m2.count_races
from meeting m1
join (select m_date, m_race_no, m_venue, count(*) count_races
      from meeting group by m_date, m_race_no, m_venue) m2
  on m1.m_date = m2.m_date
  and m1.m_race_no = m2.m_race_no
  and m1.m_venue = m2.m_venue
where m1.m_athlete = 'Bolt'
```

Comment: The group by and the join should be: `GROUP BY m_date, m_race_no, m_venue`

Comment: @ypercube i missed the primary key being all columns,, i'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    m.m_date
  , m.m_race_no
  , m.m_venue
  , COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM 
        meeting AS m
    JOIN
        meeting AS m2
            ON  m2.m_date    = m.m_date
            AND m2.m_race_no = m.m_race_no
            AND m2.m_venue   = m.m_venue
WHERE 
    m.m_athlete = 'Bolt'
GROUP BY
    m.m_date
  , m.m_race_no
  , m.m_venue
```